# Как реализовать эти задачи на практике, стажеру новичку (я даже некоторые вопросы не понял)

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. Разработать программу сортировки. Через веб интерфейс можно вводить кол-во элементов массива, который должен сортироваться
2. Написать программу минификации. Программа должна уметь минифицировать js, css и json.
3. Написать программу нормализации. Программа должна уметь из минифицированных js, css и json создавать человеко-понятный код
4. Разработать класс проверки вводимых данных. Он должен уметь проверять правильность ввода: максимальное и минимальное кол-во символов, телефон, email, только числа, только строки, дата. Все поля(кроме email) должны быть форматируемыми
5. Напишите класс, который в зависимости от числа, возвращал множественную форму в русском языке. Например 1 комментарИЙ(0), 2 комментарИЯ(1), 5 комментариЕВ(2)
6. Разработать программу, которая сможет рассчитывать разницу дат. Должна быть возможность получать разницу дат в секундах, минутах, в годах и тд(дропдаун).
7. Реализовать скрипт, который может загружать другой скрипт. После загрузки скрипта, должна появляться кнопка запуска загруженного скрипта и тело самого скрипт в нормальном виде. Загрузкой может быть как и файл, так и cdn ссылка на файл.

Comment: Мой вам совет - бегите оттуда. Это - не задачи для стажера новичка.